# Java socket programming, why browser established connection more than one time?

Tags: java, sockets, browser, webserver

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(80);
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Test");
                socket.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I use chrome to visit localhost:80, why does the server print the string "Test" 3 times? And it print twice when I use IE10 to visit it.

Comment: As the answers to this question alluded to, it is probably a bad idea to talk raw sockets when a client is talking a higher-level protocol such as HTTP: results will likely not be what you expect. What are you trying to accomplish here? Why not use an implementation of an HTTP server, which Java even includes even if in the `sun` package?

Answer (score 3):

If you printed out the HTTP request it's making, you'd probably see why. Most likely, the browser is either attempting to load `favicon.ico` for your "site" (`localhost`), or it's trying to reconnect to a server that's not speaking correct HTTP.

Answer (score 3):

When it connects to a web server it asks for a number resources like the favicon.  I suggest you print what it is asking for so you don't have guess why it is accessed more than once.